# Prediction with intervals as the independent variable

Tags: regression, machine-learning, predictive-models

I have sample data that maps intervals to a number:

```
[3,7] => 1
[6,8] => 2
[6,13] => 3
[7,10] => 3
[10,13] => 4
```

The dependent variable's values will generally increase as the intervals' values increase in a nonlinear fashion (and they're not part of a finite set, so classification won't work here).

What method(s) could be used to predict the mapped value for any given new interval?

Comment: can you perhaps treat it like a "regression with measurement error on X" problem?